# A basic question on Heisenberg uncertainty and experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, velocity, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I’m not a physicist or anything even close. But what I understand from the reason for the Heisenberg uncertainty is that the photon is changing the volecity/momentum when it hits the particle. Reflected photon I guess will estimate the position of the particle.

But here my question is about experimentation of it. Imagine a car is moving in front of me and when I take a one shot photo of it I can only verify its position when I look at the photo.

But in case of atomic particles how do they interpret the velocity by a single photo? Can this be explained in laymans terms?

Comment: I don't understand your last two paragraphs. What do you mean by "interpret the velocity"?

Comment: I mean when they send a photon to the particle the reflected photon will cause a static image so like in my car example. But. how do they see the velocity vector from that photograph of the reflected photon?

Comment: @user1999 One doesn't measure the velocity of the reflected photon from a photographic shot. Also, the uncertainty principle is inherent to quantum mechanics and persists irrespective of how precise your measurements are. I think you might be confusing the principle with the [observer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)).

Comment: How do they measure the velocity?

Comment: Your question seems to be "how does one measure the momentum of a subatomic particle?"  This is a good question but it has nothing to do with the uncertainty principle and I think you are confusing the issue by mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

The [Heisenberg uncertainty](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html), HUP,is not what you imagine, it cannot be used to get exact numbers, only probability envelopes.

If one measures the position with great accuracy, one can only measure at the same time the momentum only within the accuracy of an envelope of momentum and position $ΔxΔp> h/{2π}$, where h is a very small constant. Because $h$ is very small the HUP holds for quantum mechanical frameworks only.

> Reflected photon I guess will estimate the position of the particle.

At the quantum level it does not work that way and your car example is not similar to photon scattering. It is not particular reflected light that you see in the photograph as it passes. The car is a source of ambient light. At night the passing of a car can be recorded at a location by its own lights.

You ask:

> How do they measure the velocity?

You must mean the velocity of the particle that was hit?

By knowing the frequency of the photon sent to hit a particle, and the frequency of the scattered photon, the energy transferred can be found

by subtracting from the  incoming photon energy $hν_1$ ,  the outgoing photon energy  $hν_2$

The momentum is , $mv$ (given the mass  $m$ of the particle) and can be found by  solving the [relativistic formula](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html)

[image: energy]

where E is the transferred energy.

Momentum =$mv$ and thus the velocity of the hit particle  is measured.

The direction of the momenta /velocities is known if the direction of the first photon , and the direction of the outgoing photon are known
within errors. The position will be indeterminate, within the HUP  envelope, (supposing one knows the original and final photons directions well enough to need the HUP, usually it is measurement errors that dominate)

Comment: The question does not ask how one measures the velocity of light.

Comment: You mean the particle emits its own light(by your car example)? But then after you say scattered photon. Do they hit photon or not to the particle? Do they take photograph? I also didnt get how they measure the velocity vector.

Comment: Your new final paragraph is, I think, just what the OP was asking for.  Thanks for including it.

Comment: I did not say that the particle emits its own light. I said that the analogy of a car is wrong. The velocity of the paricle will be derived from the energy missing from the hnu1-hnu2, of the incoming and outgoing photon, equal to the 1/2mv**2 the kinetic energy of the particle that was hit (or the equivalent relativistic formula if the energy  that was transferred is high  see   http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html